# Remove backslash from string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services

I am trying to add a value to a queryparameters for reporting services programmatically.

```
 List<QueryParameter> lst = new List<QueryParameter>();
 QueryParameter qp = new QueryParameter();
 qp.Name = "@UserID";
 qp.Value = "[@UserID]";
 lst.Add(qp);
```

The values are getting inserted, but with `\` character and is it because of `@`. My QueryParameter value should be like `[@UserID]` and instead it is displayed as `\[@UserID\]`.

How can I remove the `\` from the value and the `\` doesn't show when I debug.

Really appreciate any suggestions.

**Update1:**

[image]

Comment: Where are the values inserted and where is it displayed as `\[@UserID\]`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Updated my post. When I open my rdl and check for parameters the value displays like mentioned in the image.

Comment: @RahulHendawe - `qp.value` is a `QueryParameter` and it doesn't have Split method.

Comment: Yes right try this : `string requestPath = qp.Value;` 
    
`string[] requestPathParts = requestPath.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @RahulHendawe - Stil I am able to see the `\`. Is it getting created internally somewhere or because of `@`? But I'm sure it's because of `[@` combination.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Can you pls provide any suggestions? when I add `[ ]` it causes problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing the brackets in your code?

Comment: @WEI_DBA - When I remove the brackets the value I see in parameter value is `@UserID`, but it has to be `[@UserID]` with brackets included.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your problem right:

```
testString = testString.Replace(@"\","");
```

Comment: The slashes aren't in the string itself, they're only in the UI. This code won't have any effect